# Trying to add color to column until the last row of data. Error received Object not supported. Any advice?

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to add color to the column K until the last row of data.  Error received "Object doesn't support this property or method".  I can not find what I am missing.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Sub Sumif_BD_Prem_Until_LastRow()



Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook


Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

LastRow = wb1.Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A:A").Find("Overall - Total", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 21 To LastRow

Cells(i, 19) = Application.SumIfs(wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("T:T"),   wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("K:K"), Cells(i, 3),  wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("M:M"), Cells(i, 9))

Next

With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A20:V" & LastRow).Borders
       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .Weight = xlThin
       .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("K20" & LastRow).Colors.vbBlue

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("K20" & LastRow).Colors.vbBlue

End With
```

This is the correct typing

```
Sheets("CGIBill").Range("K20" & LastRow).Interior.Color = vbBlue
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, please ,check the green arrow (answered accepted).